# java enum receive values from string name

Tags: java, string, list, enums

I have enum like:

```
public enum Enum2 
{
    ONE,TWO,THREE;
}
```

I can list all values like:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
   for (Enum2 e : Enum2.values()) 
   {
        System.out.println(e);
   }

}
```

Is it possible list values if I have only string name of Enum?

```
String enum_name="Enum2";
```

E.g. if in some logic like:

```
if (a>b) 
{
enum_name="EnumA";
} 
else
{
enum_name="EnumB";
}
```

And after I receive string name of enum - I can list all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class<?> enumClazz = Class.forName("com.mycompany.Enum2");
for (Enum<?> e : ((Class<? extends Enum<?>>)enumClazz).getEnumConstants()) {
    System.out.println(e.name()); // The variable "e" would be Enum2.ONE, etc
}
```

Thank you @Harry for helping me get this right.

Comment: You need to cast it to `(Class<? extends Enum<?>>)`

Comment: output of run: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#1-of ?> to Class<? extends Enum<?>>`

Comment: I'd use `asSubclass` instead of the dodgy cast. (Actually, I'd try to avoid getting myself in a mess that requires reflection in the first place.)

Comment: how would you use asSubClass? it accepts a Class instance as parameter, but we don't know what class it is. could you post a fragment here to show what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not much clear to be but this is what you may want to do

```
 Class<?> cls = Class.forName("EnumName");
 if (cls.isEnum()) {
   Field[] flds = cls.getDeclaredFields();
   //-- your logic for fields.
 }
```

You can use: [`Class.getEnumConstants()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29). For more see [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html).

Comment: *That* answer :)  `class` has a special method for enums

Comment: +1 For your help :) (but not the answer, sorry... but it is wrong)

Answer (score -1):

yes, with

```
Enum2.EnumA.toString();
```

Comment: he does not know Enum2 at compile time